# How on Button Delete method first get variable data than prompt for message ? My code attached

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, angularjs-scope

I am trying to update record using Angular js method my html is like,

```
<button  type="button" ng-click="delete()">'Update'</button>
```

delete method calling on angular js is,

```
$scope.delete = function () {
        tasksService.getData($scope.ids).then(function (d) {
            var result = JSON.parse(d.data.data);
        });
        if (confirm("Sure to update status +'result.name'+ For building?")) {
        }
    }
```

This code gets call on click but moved to last line confirmation after clicking on `OK` button later it call `getData` method i get result in `var result`

Actually i need to show some data from result in Confirmation Text

Hopes for your suggestions thanks

Comment: use like this    $scope.delete = function () {
                if (confirm("Sure to update status "+result.name+" For building?")) {
                    tasksService.getData($scope.ids).then(function (d) {
                        var result = JSON.parse(d.data.data);
                    });
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
               
            }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to show the confirm message in the success of the getData(). This will make the control wait for the response of getData().

```
 $scope.delete = function () {
            tasksService.getData($scope.ids).then(function (d) {
                var result = JSON.parse(d.data.data);
                if (confirm("Sure to update status " + result.name + "For building?")) {
                }
            });            
        }
```

Comment: It works but thinking i tried it before and it was not working any ways thanks

Answer (score 0):

This might help
Pass some value when function is called

> HTML

```
<button  type="button" ng-click="delete(value)">'Update'</button>
```

> JS

```
$scope.delete = function (value) { // passed value
            tasksService.getData($scope.ids).then(function (d) {
                var result = JSON.parse(d.data.data);
                if (confirm("Sure to update status " + value.name + "For building?")) {
                }
            });            
        }
```

Comment: Can i hard code value in method ng-click="delete(value=1) because i am using delete method on two buttons unable to call second time due to similarity